# Running Linux container in windows

Tags: docker, containers

I’m new to this container stuff, I understand that I unlike VMs containers don’t have operating systems in it.

But what if I build a container image under the Linux operating system and then I want to run this container image in Windows machine. How is that going to happen?

from my understanding in a container image there will only be your code and libraries. When switching between different operating systems I thought it would crash at the beginning.

can someone please correct me, really appreciate your help thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really that complicated. For example, when you use `Docker Desktop` for Windows, you can choose between using `Windows containers` or `Linux containers`. If you choose to run `Linux containers` on Windows, there are a couple of things happen in the background, but, `Docker Desktop`does that for you:

- `Hyper-V` supervisor need to be enabled on the windows machine
- Then an `Hyper-V` Linux image is downloaded
- That machine is started on `Hyper-V` and works as the new `host` for your `Linux containers`

So with that in place, when you build or run new `docker` images, all those instructions and commands run on that `Linux` virtual machine.

Also, the containers have an `operative system` but a really simple one, that's why they are so lightweight, if you need anything else that the base image doesn't have (maybe a system call or something), that container can use the host kernel to run those instructions(the host share the kernel with the running containers). It's a really good way to start with docker, to know how it works internally.

This might help to explain how it works:
[image]

Source: https://www.docker.com/whatisdocker/

Comment: Does that also mean that on Home Windows version without Hyper-V it is not possible to run Docker? I do not have a Home version available to test, just asking out of curiosity.